# Unshelving error in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We are using Team explorer 2012 connected to TFS2012. I am working by creating some workspaces.I am trying to  unshelve a shelveset by selecting a workspace in the middle of workspaces list. But it seems that changes are unshelved to workspace which is listed first in workspaces list. Why is this happening?what is the solution?

EDIT:

It seems that changes are unshelving to random workspace in list not only to first workspace

Comment: Unshelving goes to the **Active** workspace, i.e. the one selected in the Source Control Explorer. Are you sure it's not the case?

Comment: It's the one in the Team Explorer Pending Changes window actually :)

Comment: Thank you..I actually thought Active workspace is the one selected in the Source Control Explorer.Changing workspace in Team Explorer Pending Changes window certainly worked.